# Как вывести введенную матрицу с++

Tags: c++, матрицы, вывод

У меня возникла проблема, как вывести **все введенные** елементы массива, а не только последнюю строку матрицы.

```
#include <iostream>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{

int N,M;
int arr[N][M]={};

cout<<"vved kilkist ryadkiv";
cin>>N;
cout<<"vved kilkist stovpziv";
cin>>M;
cout<<"matrizia";
for(int i=0;i<N;i++ )
{
  for (int j=0;j<M;j++)
  {
    cout<<" arr["<<i<<"]["<<j<<"]=";
    cin>>arr[i][j];
  }
}
for(int i=0;i<N;i++ )
{
  for (int j=0;j<M;j++)
  {

    cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
  }
  cout<<endl;
}
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ не поддерживает массивы переменной длины. Более того вы определяете сам массив, когда его размеры еще не определены и имеют неопределенные значения. И кроме того массивы переменной длины нельзя инициализировать при их объявлении..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если переставить определение массива после ввода N и M, то матрица вводится/выводится без каких-либо проблем.

```
int N, M;
cout << "vved kilkist ryadkiv";
cin >> N;
cout << "vved kilkist stovpziv";
cin >> M;
cout << "matrizia";
int arr[N][M] = {0};
```